# javascript only works once when needed twice on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jquery-tabs

I'm using a piece of JS twice for two, different yet the same, events.

To make it more simple, let's say I've got:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".iframe").load(function(){
               $(this).contents().find("form").delegate(".clickThisCheckBox","click",function(){
                alert(this)
            })
        })
    })
</script>

<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tabs-nav">
        <li><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#accessories">Accessories</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <div id="products">
        <iframe class="iframe">
            <form action="?" method="post">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox1" class="clickThisCheckBox" />
            </form>
        </iframe>
    </div>

    <div id="accessories">
        <iframe class="iframe">
            <form action="?" method="post">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox2" class="clickThisCheckBox" />
            </form>
        </iframe>       
    </div>
</div>
```

This a more simplified version than what I've got, but exactly the same concept.

So when the page loads, you click the checkbox in the open tab, and you'll successfully get the alert box with the object. When you click the next tab and try to click the checkbox, nothing happens.

There is no AJAX or separate loading going on. Everything gets rendered on the initial page load. Both iframes are loaded at the same time and you access a different once by switching to a different tab.

Does the JS need to be in a function and ran each time a tab is clicked? Can't seem to wrap my finger around this one.

**Update**: Narrowed it down to it absolutely being that the JS only get's run once, so only the first iFrame in the first tab gets all the correct variables and events bound to the elements.

**Update**: Seemed to have figured it out. While continuing to use iFrames, I had to throw all of my JS into a function and run it on `$(".iframe").load()` and whenever a new tab is click, for example, `$(".nav-cont li a").bind("click",function(){ //run the javascript })`

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand the intent here.
Are you loading two forms in iframes and binding alerts on iframe load event?

Comment: When the page is first rendered, everything gets loaded at once. So you've got two identical iframes with identical content and one JS event to use for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bind load event to two identical iframes:

```
$("div.contents").delegate(".iframe", "load", function(){
   alert('one of the iframes loaded');
});
```

One handler function handles "load "event for both iframes.

**P.S. UPDATE**
You can't use iframes the way you explain in comments. Simply use divs instead and set overflow:hidden; If the intent is to limit the display size of that specific area with data - set this in css file:

```
.form_container{width:500px;heigth:500px;overflow:hidden;}
```

Your html then will be:

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tabs-nav">
        <li><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#accessories">Accessories</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <div id="products">
        <div class="form_container">
            <form action="?" method="post">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox1" class="clickThisCheckBox" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="accessories">
        <div class="form_container">
            <form action="?" method="post">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox2" class="clickThisCheckBox" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And js will be:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').find(':checkbox').click(function(){
        alert('something got clicked');
    })
})
</script>
```

Comment: At least to me, and certainly you, it does make more sense to use delegate() for the iframes as well. It's just not working though.

Comment: Well. can you explain what is the reason to use forms inside of iframes?

Comment: Because - you are using load event. But it'll never trigger because you don't have src attribute on your iframes. You are using iframes as some div elements - and that's incorrect. Are you trying to submit data to the backend script without reloading the page?

Comment: First off, from what I understand with the jQuery selectors, it's bad to use "div.contents", just use ".contents". 

To answer your question, I've got a large table where I loop through products and accessories and I wrote custom JS to show/hide columns and rows and do an in text search. The form is just an example, rather than pasting 300+ lines of code.. 

It's in an iframe in the first place because there is a lot of data and it would exceed 100%.

Comment: just use ".contents". - well yeah. bu thats rather the realm of microoptimization.

Comment: "it would exceed 100%". mm.. 100% of what? Are you concerned about width or heigth of the page? if so -  you can simply use div element and set width and height and overflow:hidden;

Comment: 100% width (with 20+ columns and no wrap on a majority of them.) and I'm pretty positive that it's not the iFrames that's causing. I'm guessing it's the duplicate markup and I'm not binding the events on all of them. Guess I'll try and make sure all events are using delegate when possible and then give that another try.

Comment: Your new approach can't work because I'm using an include file and you can't have an include run twice. Stuck with having to figure this one out.

Comment: this isn't the answer but I'll accept it to close the ticket and give you the points for at least trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from the code you provided you are attaching load event handlers to elements that might have not yet been loaded at the time of attaching.

Did you try to wrap your code inside `$(document).ready()` to ensure that all the elements on the page are available for manipulation before you attach event handlers to them?

Comment: Seems to be true :) I never manage to quite get a grasp of all the different kinds of closures with jQuery :D